# Should MaaS and Juju get installed on one of my servers or on a client system?

Tags: server, juju, maas

I've been struggling with MaaS and Juju slightly.  I have two servers that I want to use as nodes, but I am unsure of where to install MaaS and Juju.

Do they get installed on one of my two servers?

Can they get installed on a client system like a laptop that is not always on / on the network?

Do I need to get a very low power cheap system to run them on as my "management" system for my servers?

I hope someone can clear some of these things up for me a bit.

Comment: I think I can help you with an answer but before I get started i just want to know what exactly do you want to run on top of this setup? What's the goal of the setup?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this personal experience can help you.

Currently I am working through my POC (Proof of Concept) with only three servers. I have one thats a x86 and two that are 64-bit.

To date I have successfully had the x86 work as the node controller and region controller and enlist new nodes with MAAS. I have also been able to have a juju instance and load up some charms, deploy and expose to the web.

The only place where I am stuck is getting juju to bootstrap under MAAS. example ( juju deploy mysql --to 2 ) I think if your working through your POC and understand configuration, proper steps and methods your good to go.

Hope this helps,

John